# How to acess file from another computer in the network

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to search a particular file and  access that file by specifying the file name in a search text box  from same network just by giving the ip address and password. I am a newbie and it would be great  if some one helps me out.

Comment: What do you mean by another network? A remote computer on the internet? A computer on the same network?

Comment: This is a VERY broad question. I suggest, you do some research yourself using google.

Comment: A computer on the same network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Araf, you should first create a network share on the target machine then you can simply open the file from that network share using a UNC path, something like this:

```
\\machinename\ShareName\filename.txt
```

this should also work if you use ip address instead of machine name.